# How to return a specific status code when using JWT

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using .NET Core

The middleware seems to magically let me set up authentication and this is my code

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddCookie(option =>
            {
                     option.LoginPath = "/account/";
                //     option.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
            })
        .AddJwtBearer(jwtBearerOptions =>
                    {
                        jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            ValidateLifetime = true,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
                            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                        };
                    }
           );
```

The problem I have, is when the user calls an end point and is not authenticated the browser displays a prompt for the user to enter their username and password.

From what I've read, this is because of the response 401.

I'd like to change the response code from 401 to 400 (or any number)

I don't know how.  I can't see any options within the `AddAuthentication`

Answer (score 0):

Using HttpResponse-[OnStarting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.onstarting?view=aspnetcore-3.1) method in JwtBearerEvents-[OnAuthenticationFailed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents.onauthenticationfailed?view=aspnetcore-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.1) property:

```
jwtBearerOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
    {
        context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400;

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```